# Red light on Motherboard indicating CPU and DRAM problems

Tags: hardware-failure

Power: Corsair VS 550
Motherboard: B450 Aorus M
CPU: Amd ryzen 5
GPU: Amd radeon rx 570 (Sapphire pulse)
Ram: 1 x DDR3 8gb memory

My pc suddenly broke after normally shutting down and taking a break. So I opened it up and turned it on and found that the Motherboard was blinking red next to the labels "CPU" and "DRAM". How do I fix this? Do I just reseat the affected components?

Comment: People may be inclined to say RTFM and link to the manual https://www.gigabyte.com/au/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10#support-manual I had a quick look and it just seems to say when the light is on it's not working. If someone knows of a good SE question on troubleshooting a PC then link that. Something involving reseating components, isolation testing, knowing that motherboards require cpu fan speed sensor to work to let the system run, reset bios, check the motherboard battery, don't leave loose metal like screws under the motherboard shorting things etc. Is anything hot/cold/smelly?

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Everything seems fine and in place, the gpu and cpu fans are running properly, nothing looks loose. I have been using this pc for a few months now and it's the first time this happened. Pc just stopped working after I shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

If the system as a whole is covered by warranty from a system builder, try blowing some of the dust out, and if it still doesn't work, simply take the whole thing back to them and tell them it doesn't work.

However if you built it from parts, and you need to figure out which part(s) are faulty so you can make a warranty claim on those parts or just buy the right replacements you need to do some troubleshooting.

Your issue can be described as **"computer doesn't POST" (Power On Self Test)**. There are a bunch of tech channels with [videos demonstrating troubleshooting steps](https://www.google.com/search?q=computer%20doesn%27t%20post&tbm=vid) that basically go though a process of elimination. It's not a mysterious thing, it's just a matter of trying to identify problems and parts that are good.

While many of the tech advice places correctly say "don't assume anything" they often make incorrect deductions somewhere. This often amounts to them trying a known working part in a broken system, the broken system exhibits the same problem(s) and they incorrectly conclude the part they swapped was working. Systems may have more than 1 problem, and a broken system can break formerly good parts.

When faced with a big mystery like this, I personally like to unplug as much as possible from the broken system to have as bare a system as possible in my troubleshooting. This will always need

- Power cable
- Power supply
- Motherboard

Many motherboards require that you also have 1 each of

- CPU
- CPU fan
- RAM stick (sometimes 2 on very old systems)
  before they will make any sort of diagnostic lights or beeps. Note that for the motherboard status light and POST beeps you do NOT need any: HDD, monitor, graphics card, network, usb, keyboard, mouse, and if you know what you're doing you don't even need the case or power button. Note that when you are unplugging these, unplug both data and power.

Once you have a system that passes the tests for

- power light comes on
- and fans spin
- and POST beep code success (see https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000607.htm and https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm and your motherboard manual).

You can add 1 part at a time to test them. Note here that a part may still be good, it could be the socket that is bad, or even just that it is incompatible with something already in there. This could be that your power supply can no longer handle the load, and that next part that seems broken is overloading the PSU due to the PSU going a bit bad.

If you are unable to exclusively use parts from your system to obtain a minimal working system I advise obtaining another known working system that is parts compatible with yours, and testing your parts 1 at a time in the known working system. Note that you may break the working system with each part that you try, and the working system needs to be re-tested that it is still working between each of the parts that you test.

Problems can be any number of things, some of the obvious or strange ones that I have personally seen include:

- cables not plugged in properly at both ends. This happens a LOT.
- cables plugged in to the wrong places
- power point not switched on. I've done this a few times myself.
- that 1 power point has no power, while the rest of the building does. That 1 circuit breaker had tripped.
- broken power button
- too dusty. This can either create a short circuit or block air flow causing overheating or both. Plus it makes it rust faster if it is dusty.
- too rusty. Some of the equipment at work is in a very nasty environment.
- too burned out. (you could smell it)
- metal object pressed against one of the boards. This is normally an extra screw wedged under the motherboard.
- HDD was slowly (1~2 months) *cooking* motherboards and power supplies.
- A brand new replacement part was faulty. The most recent one of these resulted in Dell sending an entire server off to China for diagnostics. Giving us an $11000 current generation server as replacement. As nobody at Dell Australia could/wanted to figure out what was wrong with it and fix it. The new board they installed 2 weeks before, which combines power from 2 power supplies to the 1 set of cables, was what I believed the problem was. Even though I could physically see the fault on the new part, and I told them where to look, they refused to see the problem of more than 20 pins on the board not having any solder. Because it was listed in their database as new and working, and the system would work as long as you only used 3.5" HDD and not 2.5" HDDs, and you didn't mind cooking your usb devices and anything connected via the VGA port. Even though they tried swapping HDDs, raid card, raid cables, drive enclosure, both CPUs, memory, and motherboard, and the same problem persisted after all those replacements. Sorry I rant, Dell did eventually make good as they replaced an ancient 8 year old server with a brand new current generation one, but it did take months.
- memory address circuit broken on motherboard. This problem took a while as I saw that all memory slots were good, all ram sticks were good, any combination of 2 of the 4 sticks was good, it's just that when the total memory went above a certain power of 2 the system would crash when it tried to use it.
- 1 of the hdd sockets on the motherboard was broken
- 1 of the USB sockets on the motherboard was broken
- usb sockets on the front of the case shorted to the case and the power supply short circuit protection would cut the power when you touched the socket (even with a plastic stick) or just at random for fun.
- motherboard cooked a brand new power supply (there was a very loud crack noise followed by a bad smell).

And 'computer repairer' has never been my job title.

There are so many more things that could be causing the problem, basically anything you can imagine and more are possible issues. You need to go through the process of elimination.

Once you do this yourself, you can start to see why the local computer shop charges so much for this service, and why there are T-shirts that say "No, I will not fix your computer". It's time consuming and may break some of your test equipment.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, where the pc wouldnt post, while the status leds were switching between CPU and DRAM. I had to fix the bent pins on my motherboard's CPU socket, which solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177683)